# Navigate to another view via Storyboard using show - Beginner

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

It says that `Push` is deprecated. So i used `Show`. When the user clicks on the button, they directly navigate to the next view.

What i require is to execute some business logic and then based on that result to Navigate to a view. How can i do this ?

The following code doesn't even get called.

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"seguesss" sender:self];
    NSLog(@"Button Clicked");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At here

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"seguesss"]) {
        SecondViewController *vc = (SecondViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        //then vc.property = ?? or [vc method]
    }
}
```

Comment: My second viewController (destination ViewController) is called `SecondViewController`. So how can i navigate to the next screen ? What should i include as the code here. (for `segue.SecondViewController`) ?

Comment: Can you please tell me what will come for `vc.property = ?? or [vc method]`. I need to navigate the page. Sorry, I am a beginner.

Comment: @Illep I mean you could set the public property or call the public method of the second view controller in the current view controller, then execute your business logic before second view did loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard and you have linked the button to the new viewController as "Show" animation it should work without even the code you wrote above. Plus, you should have a Navigation Controller embed in the viewController where you have the button, you can do so by selecting your viewController, Editor -> Embed In - Navigation Controller